# Mean distance of the points from a fixed target point

Tags: r, average, distance, mean, arithmetic-expressions

I have some points in my data and I am trying to find the mean (arithmetic mean) distance to a target point. 
I am taking two routes here:
One, using the ['Distance Between Two Points'](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/PythagorasTheorem/pythapp.htm) formula to compute the distance between each point to the target and then getting a mean distance of those distance values.
Other, find the mean point of all points and then find the distance between this mean point and the target point.
I am not sure which approach is correct (both give different answers) if I want to get the average distance of all points to a target point?
My target point is in green and mean point is in red.
Following is my R code:

```
# three data points
a <- c(1.6, 2.3, 3.4)
b <- c(3.1, 4.1, 0.5)

# target point
t_x <- 1.1
t_y <- 0.1

df <- data.frame("x" = a, "y" = b)

# mean of the distances
df$distance <- sqrt(((df$x - t_x)^2) + ((df$y - t_y)^2)) 
print(mean(df$distance))

# distance from the mean point to the target
mean_x <- mean(df$x)
mean_y <- mean(df$y)
print(sqrt((mean_x - t_x)^2 + (mean_y - t_y)^2))

# plotting all
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5,5), ylim = c(-5,5)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=mean_x, y=mean_y), color = "red") + 
  geom_point(aes(x=t_x, y=t_y), color = "green")
```

[image: See the plot here.]

Comment: they can be both correct, depending on how you define the distance: (1) average of distances, or (2) distance to the average point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider the case with one target point and two other points

[image: two points with target in the center]

```
Target: (0,0)
Point1: (-1,0)
Point2: (1, 0)
```

If you take the average of Points 1 and 2, you get (0,0) so the average distance to the target is 0. But the distance from each of the points to the target is 1 so the mean distance in 1. In general these two calcuations are quite different

[image]

It really just comes down to how you define the problem. In this example, do you expect the answer to be 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick for the example. I re-evaluated my problem statement and found that I need to find the mean of distances.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive explanation of why your first method is the correct one. Imagine your target is at (0, 0):

```r
t_x <- 0
t_y <- 0
```

Now suppose we draw some points around it that are all the same distance from it - in fact, they all lie on the unit circle and by definition are a distance of 1 from the target:

```r
library(ggplot2)

t_x <- 0
t_y <- 0

rads <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 17)[-17]
df   <- data.frame(x = cos(rads), y = sin(rads), xend = 0, yend = 0)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(col = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), linetype = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  geom_point(x = t_x, y = t_y, size = 5, colour = "red")
```

[image]

Now, not surprisingly, since all points are distance 1 from the target, the average distance by Pythagoras will also be 1:

```r
# mean of the distances
df$distance <- sqrt(((df$x - t_x)^2) + ((df$y - t_y)^2)) 
print(mean(df$distance))
#> [1] 1
```

But now consider what happens if we take the average of all our x values - they cancel to 0. So do the y values, so the average of all points is (0, 0). When you measure the distance from (0, 0) to (0, 0), the answer, of course, is 0:

```r
mean_x <- mean(df$x)
mean_y <- mean(df$y)
print(sqrt((mean_x - t_x)^2 + (mean_y - t_y)^2))
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>